# How to set Xamarin.Forms Label Font Bold

Tags: xamarin.forms

In **Xamarin.Forms** I am using a **Label** and trying to set a **Font**.

The following code works:-

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(10);
```

However trying to specify the *Font Attributes* such like:-

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(10, FontAttributes.Bold);
```

is preventing the **ContentPage** from rendering with an exception.

There is a **Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize()**, which could be used, however this is meant to be deprecated, so I am trying to now use **Font.SystemOfSize** instead.

How is it done using this?

Comment: `Font.SystemFontOfSize()` is deprecated. Use `FontAttributes` instead i.e. `FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that works in my project:

```
new Label {
   Text = "text goes here",
   Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize (NamedSize.Medium)
              .WithAttributes (FontAttributes.Bold),
}
```

This allows you to not specify a certain font size and instead use the font size used by default for the label

Comment: This works great.  Just curious, have you managed to use both *Bold* and *Italic* at the same time using *.WithAttributes*?

Comment: I haven't but you can try `FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic`

Comment: what should we do for underline?it seems there is no option for it

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati try ExtendedLabel from the XLabs package https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel

Answer (score 36):

I guess I'm late for answering.
But still I'd like to mention that, this can be done using XAML now.
The following XAML will give the desired output.

```
<Label Text="Hello Label" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

You can refer to the following link to more about working with Fonts in Xamarin.Forms.

[Working With Fonts in XForms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/)

Comment: i Prefer FontAttributes Because Font is obsolete maybe will remove later

Answer (score 3):

Following documentation [Xamarin.Forms - Working with Fonts](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/), you should use following code:

```
Label label1 = Font.SystemFontOfSize (10, FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic)
```

Same page states that **BoldSystemFontOfSize** is deprecated.

Comment: Thats the same code I'm using.  Maybe its an issue only with using a Label control in a ContentView perhaps.

Comment: Sorry for that, this is exactly what you are using (blush). Why do you declare the label instead of using the one declared before? Show the whole form code, please

Comment: Typo - I'll correct as I was trying to give some context to the variable I'm using with.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation where the `FontAttributes="Bold"` of a Label inside a `DataTemplate` for a `ListView` were not rendered as Bold in iOS.  Android rendered fine.

When not within a `DataTemplate`, the Bold `Label` rendered correctly.

The cause was that the default font did not have a Bold available on iOS.  When I added a `Font="Arial"` to the `Label`, it correctly rendered the Bold in iOS.

I'm sharing this in case someone else has this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than one place where the bold font is required then you will be better of creating a style. Either globally in the app.cs with or without a key or in the page level. You can set all the properties you want to the appropriate values and use wherever you want.

For reference check this [page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the below in you global view.

```
<setter property="FontAttributes Value="Bold">
```